# Group memberships and setuid/setgid processes

Tags: permissions, group, setuid, setgid

Processes which *de-escalate* privileges via `setuid()` and `setgid()` do not seem to inherit the group memberships of the uid/gid they set.

I have a server process that must be executed as root in order to open a privileged port; after that it de-escalates to a specific non-privilleged uid/gid,<sup>1</sup> -- e.g., that of user `foo` (UID 73).  User `foo` is a member of group `bar`:

```
> cat /etc/group | grep bar
bar:x:54:foo
```

Hence if I login as `foo`, I can read a file `/test.txt` with these characteristics:

```
> ls -l /test.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root bar 10 Mar  8 16:22 /test.txt
```

However, the following C program (compile `std=gnu99`), when run root:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    setgid(73);
    setuid(73);
    int fd = open("/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n", fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Always reports **Permission denied**.  I imagine this has to do with it being a non-login process, but it kind of hamstrings the way permissions are supposed to work.

---

<sup>1. Which is often SOP for servers, and I think there must be a way around this as I found [a report](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.audio.sox/3136) of someone doing it with apache -- apache has been added to the audio group and can apparently then use the sound system.  Of course, this likely happens in a fork and not the original process, but in fact the case is the same in my context (it's a child process forked subsequent to the setuid call).</sup>

Comment: Switch the `setuid()`/`setgid()` calls around.

Comment: @vonbrand *ROTFL* I thought I was in for a facepalm there -- but same result, so I'll edit the question to eliminate the red herring.

Comment: If you use `setgid(54)` instead of `setgid(73)` (as in `/etc/groups`, group `bar` has gid 54), does it work?

Comment: @lgeorget Sure, but that defeats the purpose.  The process needs its own GID for other reasons, and likewise, those files must have the permissions they have.  That's why membership in groups plural is necessary -- e.g., what if you have *two* users that need to do this.  Note you can't `setuid()` again after you do it...but, hmmm...I think you can with `seteuid()`...

Comment: My question was to be sure there was no other hidden subtle problem somewhere. :-)

Comment: As one alternative you might just [give the binary CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l) and be done with it. The ability to do a `setcap +ep` though, is relatively new and requires platform support (I know RHEL 6 and most recent version of Fedora support it). This is being implemented more and more upstream as a way of getting around having to make `setuid` binaries.

Comment: @JoelDavis That's a clean and easy way to solve the problem, indeed. Maybe you could post an auto-answered question to show how a process can start, bind a socket on a privileged port, and drop its capability afterwards? That would be useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `setuid` and `setgid` are not sufficient to give your process all the credentials it needs. The authorizations of a process depend on

- its UID
- its GID
- its supplementary groups
- its capabilities.

See `man 7 credentials` to get a more detailed overview. So, in your case, the problem is that you correctly set the UID and GID, but you don't set the supplementary groups of the process. And group `bar` has GID 54, not 73,
so it is not recognized as a group your process is in.

You should do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main (void) {
    gid_t supplementary_groups[] = {54};

    setgroups(1, supplementary_groups);
    setgid(73);
    setuid(73);
    int fd = open("/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n", fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was an interesting question which deserves more upvotes because it could actually be useful to a lot of people out there. :-)

Comment: So I was having a similar issue with serial ports. I implemented this for the ```dialout``` group and it worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, trawled around the net a bit. I thought at first that [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com) would hold all the answers, but was mistaken. And my copy (old edition) is at work, so... The [Unix and Linux Administration Handbook](https://www.admin.com/)'s chapter 5 looks promising, but I haven't got it (just a copy of the first two editions, also at work).

The little resources I've found (google for "daemon writing unix") all talk about important steps, like how to dissociate from the tty, etc. But nothing about UID/GID. Strangely, not even the extensive HOWTO collection at https://tldp.org/ seems to have details. Only exception is Jason Short's [Let's Write a Linux Daemon - part I](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130125150/http://www.wordptr.com/2011/01/31/lets-write-a-linux-daemon-part-i). Full details of how SUID/SGID and all that mess works is Chen, Wagner and Dean's [SUID demystified](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edaw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf) (a paper in USENIX 2002). But be careful, Linux has an extra UID, the FSUID (see Wolter's [Unix Incompatibility Notes:
UID Setting Functions](https://unixpapa.com/incnote/setuid.html) for a discussion).

Daemonizing a process is definitely not for the faint of heart. General security considerations are given in D. Wheeler's [Secure Programming for Linux and Unix HOWTO -- Creating Secure Software](https://dwheeler.com/secure-programs/). [Systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/) promises to simplify most of that (and thus reduce the room for mistakes that lead to security problems), see the [daemon manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/daemon.html).

Comment: The question isn't about daemonization.  You've confused the SUID bit (giving a process the permissions of the owner of its executable) with `setuid()`, which allows the process to change it's UID arbitrarily.  SUID is usually intended to allow an *escalation* of permissions (non-privilleged -> privilleged), whereas `setuid()` can only do the opposite.